# Automating Proc Univariate for each variable within a dataset and printing to a pdf document

Tags: sas

How can I automate this for each variable in a dataset without having to type the code below out several times? Is it then possible to print all the graphs to a pdf document?
For example, the table class has 4 columns: sex, age, height, weight

```
PROC UNIVARIATE DATA = sashelp.class NOPRINT;
 HISTOGRAM weight / NORMAL;
RUN;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the key word `_all_`.

```
PROC UNIVARIATE DATA = sashelp.class NOPRINT;
 HISTOGRAM _all_ / NORMAL;
RUN;
```